# Adjoint mapping for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators, automorphism-group, hermitian-matrices

A mapping $\displaystyle *$ from $\displaystyle F_{n}$ to $\displaystyle F_{n}$ is called adjoint if

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
( A+B)^{*} =A^{*} +B^{*}\\
( AB)^{*} =B^{*} A^{*}\\
\left( A^{*}\right)^{*} =A;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{array}$for all $\displaystyle A,B\in F_{n}$

If we know $\displaystyle \psi $ is an automorphism of $\displaystyle F_{n}$ in such a way that $\displaystyle \psi ( A+B) =\psi ( A) +\psi ( B)$ and $\displaystyle \psi ( AB) =\psi ( A) \psi ( B)$ such that $\displaystyle \psi ( \lambda ) =\lambda $ for every scalar matrix $\displaystyle \lambda \in 
F_{n}$. then there is an element $\displaystyle P\in F_{n}$ such that $\displaystyle \psi ( A) =PAP^{-1}$ for all $\displaystyle A\in F_{n}$.

From this theorem, **prove that**

**if $\displaystyle \ast $ is an adjoint of $\displaystyle F_{n}$ such that $\displaystyle \lambda ^{*} =\lambda $ for every scalar matrix $\displaystyle \lambda $ then there exists a matrix $\displaystyle P\in F_{n}$ such that $\displaystyle A^{*} =PA'P^{-1}$ for every $\displaystyle A\in F_{n}$.**

$\displaystyle F_{n}$ is the set of all $\displaystyle n\times n$ matrices over $\displaystyle F$.

Please give me hints to prove this.

**Edit: Moreover prove that $P^{-1}P'$ must be scalar.**

Comment: By $A'$, you mean $A$, right?

Comment: No, $\displaystyle A'$ is transpose of $\displaystyle A$.
This question is asked in chapter 6 of  **topics of algebra** by **I N Herstein**.

Comment: Oh right... I guess I need my morning coffee! You can start by defining $\psi(A)=A'^*$

Comment: Further in this question it is asked that  $\displaystyle P^{-1} P'$ must be scalar. I am trying to prove this by showing that $\displaystyle \left( P^{-1} P'\right)^{*} =P^{-1} P'$ but, I am unable to show this. Could you please tell me how can I prove this?